# Debugging QGIS plugin using pdb

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, debugging

I typically use pdb for debugging. However, when I follow the docs for [debugging with pdb](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/ide_debugging.html?highlight=pdb#debugging-using-pdb), I get the error:

> input(): lost sys.stdin

I'm developing my plugin straight out of the load directory:

`%APPDATA%\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\my_tool`

The minimal files are:

**metadata.txt**

```
[general]
name=My Tool
email=dood@example.com
author=dood
qgisMinimumVersion=3.10
description=My Tool
about=Software for stuff
version=version 0.1
repository=http://www.itopen.it/repo

experimental=True
```

****init**.py**

```py
def classFactory(iface):
    from .my_tool import MyTool
    return MyTool(iface)
```

**my_tool.py**

```py
import qgis
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class MyTool:

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface

    def initGui(self):
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction("My Tool", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)

    def unload(self):
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)

    def run(self):
        print("Running my tool")

        import pdb
        from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import pyqtRemoveInputHook
        pyqtRemoveInputHook()
        pdb.set_trace()
```

I have [First Aid](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/firstaid/) installed. It works, but I can't type more than one line at a time. Commands like code stepping and 'interact' don't seem to exist.